# PHP: What options are there to refactor double used classname?

Tags: php, namespaces

On a web project there are two classes that have the same name. This was never an issue until now, because the two classes where never used at the same time / in the same script.

Now we require to use both classes in one script, and therefor got ourselves an "Cannot redeclare class" fatal error.

My question is: What options are there to resolve this issue?

The one possible solution would be to rename one of the classes in question, but it is something I would very much like to avoid - one of the classes is part of a third-party software that should not be modified at this level, to remain updateable.

I know there are namespaces - are they a valid option to this problem? I have never used namespaces until now.

Assuming we would put one of the classes into a namespace: Would this resolve the issue? Also, what measures would we need to take to access the now-namespaced class?

Comment: PSR-0 reconciles all this https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Comment: Namespaces are definitely the way to go. All non-trivial code should be implemented using namespaces these days.

Comment: Definitely, you may use namespace.

Comment: If you've hit this issue once, you're likely to hit it again. Invest the time to learn about namespaces - which exist solely to avoid problems like this. You'll probably thank yourself later...

Comment: if our are instantiating the object just once then change the class name :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Namespace work:
 consider we have 2 classes named User  in file structure

```
/Package1/User.php
```

with content

```
<?php
    namespace Package1;
    class user {...}
```

and

/Package2/User.php

with content

```
<?php
    namespace Package2;
    class user {...}
```

and now for some reason we decide to use both in some class UserManager in:
    /Package3/UserManager.php
with content:

```
<?php
    namespace /Package3;
   use  package1/User as User1;
   use  package2/User as User2;
   class UserManager {
       public function __construct(User1 $user1, User2 $user2) {...}
       ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces would surely solve your problem.
For example I got multiple classes named 'core', but because they're all classes of a different namespace it doesn't give any conflict at all.

This does mean you have to go over all your code and refer to the namespaced class with the correct path.

```
$item = new doubleClass();
```

would become

```
$item = new \my_namespace\doubleClass();
```

Also make sure that your other scripts don't get namespaced otherwise it wouldn't be able to find the non namespaced class anymore.

Comment: It doesn't have to mean go over everything to change it to the fully qualifiedclass name -> if your file `someFile` is in the same namespace as that `doubleClass`, you wouldn't need to prepend the namespace -> so by choosing your namespaces carefully and having some luck with your current code, it could be easier than changing all.